# How to edit existing shape radius in Adobe Photosho CS6

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6

I have rectangle shape with radius 5, but now i need to edit it to 10. Adobe Photoshop CC have that feature, but can't find solution for CS6.

I do new shape with exact same size and border radios 10 in the same place and then remove the previous one.

I am looking for faster/easier way in Adobe CS6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no solution for CS6 other than to redraw the rectangle with the new radius or manually adjust the anchors of a shape/vector layer.

Comment: Ah OK thanks a lot. Time to buy Adobe Photoshop CC then.

Answer (score 0):

If it still need, there is one way. You must download Corner Editor Script. You can round the corners of any polygonal shape within script. For easier access, make an action or add a keyboard shortcut. As with the Rounded Rectangle Radius Resizer script, you can also
– View the pixel radius of existing rounded rectangles
– Edit multiple layers at once
– Apply a different radius to each corner and/or subpath

[**Download script**](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cornereditor/files/latest/download) — [**Source**](https://photoshopscripts.wordpress.com/2013/02/03/corner-editor-photoshop-script/)

Answer (score 0):

Just select the layer on which shape is being drawn and then drag your mouse to the rectangle tool or press U for short-cut than at top the radius will  be displayed from where you can change the radius